# Intellisense cache deleted every time I close a file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have found that there are common issues around the fact that sometimes, Visual Studio won't compile a typescript file when it's being saved (solved by ticking a checked box), or won't compile typescript files during a project build (solved by adding a line in the .csproj file).

However my issue is different, my typescript files are compiled on save, and all the typescript files are compiled when I build the project.

However for some reason, if I close my project and reopen it, all the intellisense is broken and I have to go through every file and save them. Moreover, I have found that if I close a typescript file - just closing the tab - the intellisense cache for this file is cleared and I get everything underlined in red.

I mean that if I declared an Address class in a file and close it, Address becomes unknown for intellisense in all the other files.

As you can imagine this is very unpractical, and I don't quite see how to fix that.

Any idea ?

**Update**

I found a modest workaround to make my life somehow better. If I create a _reference.ts file and add references to all the typescript files in my project, then I just have to keep this file open to have intellisense working in all other files (if I close this file, all the identifiers are unknown again)

Comment: `As you can imagine this is very unpractical, and I don't quite see how to fix that` don't use visual studio `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript

Comment: @basarat I stopped that, it is too much hassle for time being. I'd need to redesigne my whole development workflow, source control management etc.... Not something I want to get into now